# Xamarin EF Core Data Seeding

Tags: c#, entity-framework, xamarin, .net-core, .net-standard-2.0

Recently we got support of EF in Xamarin (.Net Standard 2 and .Net Core). And it works, but i havent found any information about data seeding. For example in usual ef application we have EntityFramwork options like "databaseInitializer" and several classes like DropCreateDatabaseAlways...

Can you give me the reference at the solution for this task in xamarin?

Comment: Have you seen the ef core docs? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding

Comment: Thx a lot! I will try use migrators.